# Are static constructors triggered from OnAppStart safe to use in a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using static Constructors to initialization my helper classes with their foundational information. The static Constructors are triggered by `Application_Start` by initializing an instance.

My concern has arisen because, in one of these constructors I issues a call grab an object from the Database using Entity framework. But the returned object was always `null`, and I'm sure its because it fired too early in the life-cycle (before EF had fully finished or something)

So my question is, is this solution architecture safe?
(below is called by `Application_Start`)

```
public static void OnAppInit()
        {
            AppSettings AS = new AppSettings(); //Trigger static constructor
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            GeneralConfig.OnAppStart();
            ElmahConfig EC = new ElmahConfig(); //Trigger static constructor
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
            ViewResourceHelper VRH = new ViewResourceHelper(); //Trigger static constructor
            ExceptionHelper EH = new ExceptionHelper(); //Trigger static constructor
            TestEnvironmentHelper.Init();
        }
```

Comment: If something else hadn't finished initializing, I'd have expected an exception rather than a silent null return value... Have you debugged into it?

Comment: Why are you using static constructors to initialize your code? You can call the code explicitly from `OnAppInit`. Hiding database calls into static constructors is not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Doing any serious work in a static constructor is not a recommended design. In fact, check out Eric Lippert's recent blog post series on static constructors. In his [latest post](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/18/static-constructors-part-four/) he specifically says:

> In short: Static constructors should be used to quickly initialize important static data, and that's pretty much it.

And if it's coming from Eric Lippert, I'd say it's as good as gold.

The alternative I would recommend is using [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).